# Solr how can I have the original term first than the stemmed version?

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj, stemming

I have been trying to get the exact key matched result first in the Solr 5.0.0 result.

For Example,

- Meditation Bowls
- Goddess Bowls
- Celestial Bowls
- Bowling Green
- 33 Bowls Tibetan Singing Bowls
- Dust Bowl Revival
- Bowl of Stars

If I search for a word `bowl`, the expected results are:

1. Dust Bowl Revival
2. Bowl of Stars
3. Meditation Bowls
4. Goddess Bowls
5. Celestial Bowls
6. Bowling Green
7. 33 Bowls Tibetan Singing Bowls

The exact word contained results shoud come first.
My schema is given below:

```xml
 <fieldType name="text_wslc" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer type="index">
     <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
     <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                             generateWordParts="1"
                             generateNumberParts="1"
                             catenateWords="1"
                             catenateNumbers="1"
                             catenateAll="1"
                             preserveOriginal="1"
                             />
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.KeywordRepeatFilterFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.KStemFilterFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
     <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
     <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                             generateWordParts="1"
                             generateNumberParts="1"
                             catenateWords="1"
                             catenateNumbers="1"
                             catenateAll="1"
                             preserveOriginal="1"
                             />
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.KeywordRepeatFilterFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.KStemFilterFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
 </fieldType>
```

I had seen that using `KeywordRepeatFilterFactory` gives the exact matched one then stemmed version. But it's not working for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can add another field in the **schema.xml**. This one will contains the copy of your original field:

```xml
<field name="title" type="text_wslc" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="titleExact" type="text_wslcExact" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<copyField source="title" dest="titleExact"/>
```

Where `text_wslcExact` is something like that:

```xml
<fieldType name="textExact" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" >
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LimitTokenCountFilterFactory" maxTokenCount="20"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LimitTokenCountFilterFactory" maxTokenCount="20"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
```

Next thing to do is to add (and boost) this new field to your query. So, in your **solrconfig.xml**, try to do something like that:

```xml
<str name="qf">title titleExact^10</str>
<str name="pf">title^10 titleExact^100</str>
```

[Here is my source](http://everydaydeveloper.blogspot.fr/2012/02/solr-improve-relevancy-by-boosting.html) where you can have all the explainations.

Comment: is that give result contains the word as search word first than its stemmed version?

Comment: Actually no boost is necessary as the exact match will receive a better score just by finding it in both indexes (title & titleExact)

Comment: It depends of how its score is calculated. If the score is only the maximum score of all these fields (like [it is for Dismax parser without using `tie` parameter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#tie_.28Tie_breaker.29)), the boost is needed, isn't it?

Comment: Hm, I guess you're right in that case. I had in mind a simpler BooleanQuery, something like: +title:term titleExact:term which would naturally boost matches in both fields.

Comment: @alexf <str name="qf">title titleExact^10</str>
<str name="pf">title^10 titleExact^100</str>
Under which request handler i have to add these things?

Comment: The `requestHandler` that you usually use. If you don't use a `requestHandler`, use what spyk said !